# Insert data into SQL Server database from an Excel file

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, wcf

I'm trying to insert data to database using excel file. This code works fine for me. But I used this with windows form application. How can I change this code to WCF? I need to open Excel file using Windows Forms application and then pass the value to WCF service to insert data into the database. How can I do this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog opn = new OpenFileDialog();
    opn.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

    if (opn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;

    try { 
        FileStream strm = new FileStream(opn.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        IExcelDataReader excldr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(strm);

        DataSet rslt = excldr.AsDataSet();

        DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        foreach (DataTable table in rslt.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                tblExcel addTbl = new tblExcel()
                                  {
                                    SID = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
                                    Name = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                                    Address = Convert.ToString(dr[2])
                                  };
                conn.tblExcels.InsertOnSubmit(addTbl);
            }
        }

        conn.SubmitChanges();

        excldr.Close();
        strm.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("successfully");
    }
    catch (IOException x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create a WCF service.

**Assumption made:** 
Let’s say you have a list of `tblExcel` objects that you want to send to a WCF service from you WinForm client application shown in your question.

**Step 1:**
Create a new Class Library project and name it ExcelDataService
In this project create a new folder called “`DataContracts`” and under this folder create a new class with the following definition:

```
[DataContract]
public class ExcelData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Sid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; } 
}
```

*Note: tblExcel is renamed as ExcelData, the definition of the class is the same you posted in original question.*

**Step 2:**
Create another folder named “`ServiceContracts`”under ExcelDataService project and create a new interface with the following definition

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExcelDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveData(List<ExceData> data);
}
```

**Step 3:**
Next create another folder and name it “`Services`” and create a new class with the following definition

```
public class ExcelDataService : IExcelDataService
{
    public bool SaveData(List<ExceData> data)
    {

        // Showing the code how to save into SQL is beyond this question.
        // In the data object you have the list of excel data objects that you can save into the sql server
        // you can use Enterprise Library Data block or ADO.Net to save this data into the SQL Server.

    }
}
```

**Step 4a:**
Now in the visual studio solution add a new project and name it `ExcelDataServiceConsoleHostManager`, set the type of project as Console Application. In the `Main` method write the following code:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExcelDataService)))
{
     PrintEndpoints(host.Description);
     host.Open();
     Console.WriteLine("Service(s) are up and running... Press Enter key to exit!");
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Step 4b:**
Add another static method with the following definition:

```
 static void PrintEndpoints(ServiceDescription desc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(desc.Name);
            foreach (ServiceEndpoint nextEndpoint in desc.Endpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(nextEndpoint.Address);
            }
        }
```

**Step 5:**
In the App.config file of this project add the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ExcelDataService.Services.ExcelDataService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8887/ExcelDataService/"
                   binding="netTcpBinding"
                   contract="ExcelDataService. ServiceContracts.IExcelDataService"
                  ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Make sure all the references are added** into the project. Once build is successful hit F5 key to start the Excel Data Service Console Host manager.

Next step is modifying your client application:

**Step 6:**
Add a reference of “ExcelDataService.dll” in your client application. 
Create a new class with the following definition:

```
public class ExcelDataServiceClient : ClientBase<IExcelDataService>
{
    public bool SaveData(List<ExcelData> excelData)
    {
        base.Channel.SaveData(excelData);
    }
}
```

**Step 7:**
Add app.config file into your client (if already not added) and paste the following configuration

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8887/ExcelDataService/"
                 binding="netTcpBinding"
                 contract="ExcelDataService. ServiceContracts.IExcelDataService"></endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Save all files and resolve any references (WCF uses System.ServiceModel.dll).

**Step 8:**
Next create a new instance of `ExcelDataServiceClient` class and call its instance method SaveData.

I would wrap the call from the client into a `try-catch` block to catch any exception.

**Edit 2:**
To send a file to WCF service we have

Request class that client will use to send the file...

```
 [DataContract]
 public class UploadFileRequest
 {
       public string FileName { get; set; }
       public string Path { get; set; }
       public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }
 }
```

and the response class that service will send back:

```
[DataContract]
public class UploadFileResponse
{
     public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

add another method to the IExcelDataService interface:

```
 [OperationContract]
 UploadFileResponse UploadFile(UploadFileRequest request);
```

and its implementation in the ExcelDataService class:

```
public UploadFileResponse UploadFile(UploadFileRequest request)
{
// In the request object you have the file as byte array that can be used here.             
}
```

On the client side add this method in the ExcelDataServiceClient class

```
public string UploadFile(byte[] fileContent, string fileName = "", string filePath = "")
{
    UploadFileRequest request = new UploadFileRequest()
    {
         FileContents = fileContent, FileName = fileName, Path = filePath
    };

    UploadFileResponse response =  base.Channel.UploadFile(request);

    return response.Message;
}
```

Next use the instance of this client class to call UploadFile method and pass in the parameters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you +1
it's to0 hard to me, coz I'm new to wcf ,anyway I'll try ...
thanks again :D

Comment: can I pass the file DataSet rslt as parameter to WCF method ?

Comment: Yes you can pass any file in a byte array (byte[] ) to WCF service. I have written a service that takes MS Word documents in byte[] and process them then eventually saves them into a SQL Database.

Comment: how can I use byte[] array in there ,can you provide me sample here,plz :(

Comment: Added Edit 2 in the answer showing support for file transfer.

Comment: Thank u :) i'll try

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options for you to consider.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Coding\\DOT.NET\\Samples C#\\Export DataGridView to SQL Server Table\\Import_List.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

    ExcelConnection.Open();

    string expr = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection);
    OleDbDataReader objDR = null;
    SqlConnection SQLconn = new SqlConnection();
    string ConnString = "Data Source=Excel-PC;Initial Catalog=Northwind.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString;
    SQLconn.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn))
    {

        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblTest";

        try
        {
            objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR);
            ExcelConnection.Close();

            //objDR.Close()
            SQLconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

ALSO

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();
}

protected void BindGrid()
{
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Coding\\DOT.NET\\Samples C#\\Export DataGridView to SQL Server Table\\Import_List.xls";
    string jet = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(jet);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    BulkUpload();
}

    protected void BulkUpload()
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        string connection = "Data Source=excel-pc;Initial Catalog=Northwind.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            try{

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "Fname");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "Lname");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "Age");

                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Import_List";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt.CreateDataReader());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errors.Add("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Remember, you need these at the top.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: Thanks , but there are no WCF connections